# Unable to Deploy/Migrate to Mainnet via Truffle/Infura

Tags: contract-deployment, gas-limit, gas-price, truffle-deployment, mainnet

On 12/26/2020 I successfully compiled, migrated and tested on Ropsten via Truffle the following contract https://github.com/estudios-amazonia/FilmVault/blob/main/contracts/FVP_Token.sol.
See Ropsten Contract Address: 0x82Bc5871e30FB2C00A3E5B5E6475A2baD88978ba

Today, 12/27/2020 I have been trying to deploy the same contract using the same truffle-config.js file on Mainnet and it gets frozen after compilying. I have used an array of gas / gasPrice combinations. The latest is as follows:

```
mainnet: {
  networkCheckTimeout: 100000000,
  provider: function() {
    return new HDWalletProvider(maimnem, 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3' + key);
},
  network_id: 1,
  gas: 4000000,
  gasPrice: 65000000000, // 65Gwei
```

Therefore, I tried to use Remix, with GASLIMIT 350000 and VALUE 60 Gwei and it has failed twice. See the following Tx
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xdbdbe42e7f937f18952db19e94c6e6b42628f90241653f06d724999e278698e5
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x794243d66ba78ab9b349bb0a9abd38c3b2e6de55b396dd7a6b6a1f6258cff005

Would anyone be able to help me troubleshoot what is going on with this migration on Mainnet?

Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Although I was unable to deploy/migrate via Truffle/Infura with plenty ETH, the contract was finally deployed/migrated via Remix/Metamask by setting GAS LIMIT=800000 and VALUE=0 at a non-peak time.

See https://etherscan.io/tx/0xde603058609d800d0ee2ccc5cf4cfa086a7161a25b9ce774cabae52a7514282c

Answer (score 0):

The contract you are trying to deploy has a non-payable constructor and you are sending a 0.00000008 Ethers.

From the [transaction trace](https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x794243d66ba78ab9b349bb0a9abd38c3b2e6de55b396dd7a6b6a1f6258cff005)

```
[1]     0   PUSH1       238732  3   1
[2]     2   PUSH1       238729  3   1
[3]     4   MSTORE      238726  12  1
[4]     5   CALLVALUE   238714  2   1
[5]     6   DUP1        238712  3   1
[6]     7   ISZERO      238709  3   1
[7]     8   PUSH2       238706  3   1
[8]     11  JUMPI       238703  10  1
[9]     12  PUSH1       238693  3   1
[10]    14  DUP1        238690  3   1
[11]    15  *REVERT     238687  0
```

Comment: Dear Ismael, thanks for your prompt answer. Could you please shed some light on how exactly I need to modify the contract so that it deploys/migrates into Mainnet?

Comment: and I mean, via Truffle/Infura. Since I would not want to try to deploy via Remix again and wast ETH...

Comment: @g.a.mercado Just don't send ether with the deployment transaction. If you want more details add deployment script to the question.

Comment: Ismael,Those two transactions were generated while deploying/migrating via Remix, which I resorted to since the command "truffle migrate --network mainnet --reset" would just stay there for hours after compiling...

Comment: The contract I am deploying is https://github.com/estudios-amazonia/FilmVault/blob/main/contracts/FVP_Token.sol, which I had deployed an identical version via Truffle/Infura over a year ago, with a simplified version of the "constructor"

Comment: @g.a.mercado I see nothing wrong with the migrations script nor the truffle-config.js. If you want to use truffle make sure the mnemonic is correct, and the account has enough ether, no pending transactions. Check the infura key is valid, make sure you have a good gas price. To use remix make sure value is 0 wei in deploy & run transactions, the gas price is adjusted from metamask.

Comment: Ahhhh, I understand now... The VALUE has to be 0 . Thanks a lot. Let me try with REMIX again

Comment: I jut tried with REMIX with a GAS LIMIT of 90000 and VALUE 0, and the trasnaction at Metamask indicated that it would cost $35...   Does that mean that If I want to run it via Truffle/Infura, I have to have at least that ammount on my ETH Account?

Comment: @g.a.mercado The recommended gas price changes all the time, right now it is above 100gwei. The truffle configuration had 4000000, so you will need x5, also migrations scripts make several transaction (4 I think) so you will need more x4. I never liked that behavior, for mainnet I prefer to run my own scripts.

Comment: Dear @ismael.

Thanks so much for your guidance. We will ensure we have plenty of ETH on our Metamask account so that we can run the deployment/migration scripts via Truffle/Infura.

Would you please provide your ETH address? Our team would like to grant you a gift of appreciation. 

PS: What do you mean by that you run your own scripts in Mainnet?

Comment: @g.a.mercado I used to write a small js file that deploys the contracts (skipping the extra transactions that are not needed), now there are tools like hardhat that make it easier. If you want to send something I'll add an address to my profile.

Comment: Dear Ismael, we have successfully deployed/migrated our contract on Mainnet via Remix. Thanks for your recommendations. As noted, we just sent 20 TFF to your ETH wallet 0x3DA55f052f1Db425c93A944937faeB361cf6d35D ; please see https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc1114a9b69d574b6a440ef21d0e0f73a9e7e5da9d1b6bb45ef0464515018145d. For details about our project, please visit https://github.com/estudios-amazonia/TheFaustFlick; and stay abreast by following our twitter account and joining our telegram community, specially since we will be performing a TFF swap during Q1-2021. Cheers and all the best for you.